# A script that finds a matching color to the photo

Tags: image, colors

I'm a graphic designer and often I make websites. I am looking for a script (may ultimately be even software) that finds ONE matching color to the photo. A very good illustration of this is that page: https://unsplash.com/grid If refered your mouse on the picture it shows a matching color. This is a screenshoot that I show this issue: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65947165/qu1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ImageMagick and find the average colour by resizing the image to 1 pixel x 1 pixel and converting that pixel to text, like this:

```
convert photo-1414637104192-f9ab9a0ee249.jpg -resize 1x1! -colorspace RGB txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,rgb
0,0: (0,21,3)  #001503  rgb(0,21,3)
```

So rgb(0,21,3) is the green leaf with the drop of water from your example. You can have it as sRGB like this:

```
convert photo-1418479631014-8cbf89db3431.jpg -resize 1x1! txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,srgb
0,0: (141,109,91)  #8D6D5B  srgb(141,109,91)
```

If you want it as an image, you would do this:

```
convert photo-1414637104192-f9ab9a0ee249.jpg -resize 1x1! -scale 1000 output.jpg
```

[image]

This is the first image from your example page...

[image]

I don't really speak `PHP`, but this should be close:

```
<?php 
$image = new Imagick('input.jpg'); 
$image->resizeImage(1,1,Imagick::FILTER_BOX,1);
$pixel = $image->getImagePixelColor(0,0); 
print $pixel->getColorAsString();
$colors = $pixel->getColor(); 
print_r($colors);
?>
```

**Output**

```
srgb(55.259%,42.2065%,34.9279%)Array
(
    [r] => 141
    [g] => 108
    [b] => 89
    [a] => 1
)
```